# lost uncommitted changes when did git reset --hard origin/master

Tags: git, bitbucket

[image: git reflog]
How can i recover the changes from the code,i have tried`git reset 'HEAD@{1}'` but didn't see the changes .

Comment: `--hard` tells `git reset` to *discard* uncommitted changes. There is no in-Git way to get them back.

Comment: Move away from a “one commit per day” mentality. Commit often in future and this sort of thing can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact situation for a couple of minutes ago and from a git point of view if you have not stashed or shelved your changes there's not much to do **BUT**  if you are using and IDE like IntelliJ IDEA you can recover those files by looking at your local project history see:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html#restore-files-from-local-history